# Python: Updating a textvariable but getting attribute error

Tags: python, user-interface, attributes

I have a `Label` whose `textvariable` is a `StringVar`, initially set to 0. After a certain button is pressed, the I want the `Label` to be updated with relevant information from the button-press. Let me first show the code:

```
#dictionary module contains some custom functions
#to be used later
from dictionary import *

import os
import pickle
from tkinter import *

#file_path is what will be the text
#for the entry box
file_path = ''

#SampleApp allows for frames to be stacked on top of each other
class SampleApp(Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, ProcessPage, ReviewPage):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, c):
        '''Show a frame for the given class'''
        frame = self.frames[c]
        frame.tkraise()

#The first page the user sees, has a dynamic label which shows
#the number of words in the dictionary
class StartPage(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        #Variable string for the word number
        self.Total_words_text = StringVar()
        self.Total_words_text.set('Total number of words in dictionary: 0')

        Total_words = Label(self, textvariable = self.Total_words_text)
        Total_words.pack()

        #This button leads to another page allowing user to process
        #more text files
        Add_more_words_btn = Button(self, text ='Add more words',
                                    command=lambda: controller.show_frame(ProcessPage))
        Add_more_words_btn.pack(side = LEFT, anchor = 's',expand = TRUE, fill = X)

        #Goes to the flash-card game
        Review_btn = Button(self, text='Review',
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(ReviewPage))
        Review_btn.pack(side = LEFT, anchor = 's',expand = TRUE, fill = X)

#This page allows the user to process more documents
#and increase the word count
class ProcessPage(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        Instruction_label = Label(self, text = 'Please enter the path of your text-file below:')
        Instruction_label.pack(side = 'top')

        self.Path_box = Entry(self, textvariable = file_path)
        self.Path_box.pack(expand = True, fill = 'x')

        Browse_btn = Button(self, text = 'Browse', command = self.browse_text)
        Browse_btn.pack(expand = True, fill = 'x')

        Process_btn = Button(self, text = 'Process', command = self.process_path)
        Back_btn = Button(self, text = 'Back',
                          command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))

        Process_btn.pack(side='left', fill='x', expand = True, anchor='sw')

        Back_btn.pack(side='right', fill='x', expand = True, anchor='se')

    #This function is what the "Browse" Button does, it pulls
    #up a file browser, allows the user to select a file,
    #then puts the path of the file into the entry box
    def browse_text(self):
        global file_path

        from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
        filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
        file_path = os.path.normpath(filename)
        self.Path_box.delete(0, END)
        self.Path_box.insert(0, file_path)

    #This function is bound to the "Process" button
    #It gets the path from the entry box, and processes
    #the document, it then loads the freq_dict, and updates
    #the label's textvariable in the start page
    def process_path(self):
        path_name = self.Path_box.get()
        process_book(path_name)
        self.Path_box.delete(0, END)

        freq_dict = load_dict('svd_f_dict')
        dict_words_num = len(freq_dict.keys())
        StartPage.Total_words_text.set(dict_words_num)

#WIP, will allow user to play a SRS flash-card game
class ReviewPage(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        Start_btn = Button(self, text = 'Start Review')
        Back_btn = Button(self, text = 'Back',
                          command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        Define_btn = Button(self, text = 'Define new words')

        Start_btn.pack()
        Back_btn.pack(side='left', fill='x', expand = True, anchor='se')
        Define_btn.pack(side = 'right', fill = 'x', expand = True, anchor = 'sw')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()`
```

This program is supposed to take a user-specified foreign language text-file, process it (by breaking up, counting, sorting and then building a dictionary with all unique words in the text-file).

What I want is the start page to show the total number of words in the frequency dictionary. Initially it should be zero (since no documents have been processed), then when a document has been processed the label should be updated according to the number of keys in the pickled frequency dictionary (called `freq_dict`). The trouble is I don't know how to make it so that the textvariable actually updates whenever the process button is pressed. What I have tried above returns the following error:

```
>>> 
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1487, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\User 3.1\Desktop\Code Projects\test.py", line 105, in process_path
    StartPage.Total_words_text.set(dict_words_num)
AttributeError: type object 'StartPage' has no attribute 'Total_words_text'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `self.controller = controller` in `__init__`, and use `self.controller.frames[StartPage]` to access the *instance* of `StartPage` in `ProcessPage.process_path`:

```
import functools 
class ProcessPage(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        ...
        self.controller = controller
        Process_btn = Button(
            self, text = 'Process', 
            command = self.process_path)

    def process_path(self):
        ...
        self.controller.frames[StartPage].Total_words_text.set(dict_words_num)
```

The reason why your code was not working is because `Total_words_text` is an
attribute of the *instance* of `StartPage`, not an attribute of the class
`StartPage`.

Each frame is passed the controller, an instance of SampleApp.
The SampleApp instance has an attribute `self.frames[StartPage]` which points to the StartPage instance. So  `controller.frames[StartPage].Total_words_text` will access the desired Total_words_text attribute.

Comment: he is not calling it from in the StartPage class ... he is calling it from another class... he needs to use a classmethod or a static method or he needs to create an instance of startpage ...